# Regex multiple catch-all setup in postfix

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I need to setup a regex catch-all function on postfix such that:

- **tom.(anything)@domain.com** goes to **tom@other.com**
- **phil.(anything)@domain.com** goes to **phil@other.com**

How can this be achieved in postfix?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add this to your main.cf:

```
alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/aliases
```

Then create `/etc/postfix/aliases` as follows:

```
/^tom\..*@domain.com$/     tom@other.com
/^phil\..*@domain.com$/    phil@other.com
```

See the [regexp table](http://www.postfix.org/regexp_table.5.html) documentation for additional information.

Comment: I setup as suggested. getting bounce as: (Action: failed, Status: 5.1.1, Diagnostic-Code: x-unix; user unknown). I checked postconf -m and saw regexp supported but still not working. bounce complain tom.curry@domain.com is not a real mailbox, but thats the point of alias. it should relay mail to tom@other.com which is elsewhere without complaining.
(I use postfix with working mailman lists on ubuntu if that helps)

Comment: You may need to configure virtual aliases, etc if domain.com is a virtual alias.

Comment: thanks! called it virtual_alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/aliases and got it running.

Comment: Is it possible to use those kind of regexp in an LDAP setup?

Answer (score 4):

I'll add this for people who are wondering if it is possible to handle multiple address aliases with less configuration:

```
/^(.*)\..*@domain.com$/     $1@other.com
```

This will forward:

`<anything>.<part_b>@domain.com`

to

`<anything>@other.com`

Comment: What is part_b?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know Postfix, but the regex you're looking for is:

```
/^.*(\..*)@(domain).com$/
```

Then you substitute the first matching group with nothing (empty string), and the second group with "other".

As an example, in Perl you would do:

```
my $regex = '^.*(\..*)@(domain).com$';

$your_string =~ /$regex/;
$aux = $2;
$your_string =~ s/$1//;
$your_string =~ s/$aux/other/;

print $your_string;
```

Of course this works only if email address has "domain" as domain. If you want domain to be anything, then the regex would be:

```
^.*(\..*)@(.*).com$
```